# How to debug an Android built application that works perfectly in dev and doesn't return a warning or error?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm new in the react-native/expo community.

I developped an app with expo. I have no warning or error in dev.
When I publish my app on expo server, all works well.

However, when I make an android build, and install it on my device, I got a bug.

I got a drawer, with many links. But only one of them make restart the app on the first click on it an freeze the app on the second click.

I tried to debug with Sentry, but they are no log into Sentry when my app crash.

I don't know how to debug this kind of problem, so I ask here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please change the debugging setting of the mobile phone to On. And after connecting a cell phone to your computer,  run the Android studio, to check the log.

Comment: I ll test your solution and I ll go back to keep you informed.

Comment: This solution was a good idea. But for a junior it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install react-native-debugger as mentioned in the expo docs. i've used that and its pretty good for debugging the error.

[EXPO DEBUGGING](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/debugging/)

`you can check the above link.

and you can download via `brew cask install react-native-debugger`

Hope it helps , feel free for doubts.

Comment: This solution is not suitable applications installed on device's client. I thuink it's for development only.

Comment: yeah, ffor production you ave to use sentry

Comment: That's what I ve done.  But I get any error or warning logged. I think I ll test the solution mentionned above. Link my phone with debug enabled to my computer and see  logs into android studio.